# How to remove space between text using Bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing the form using Bootstrap. I wanted to remove the space between `send inquiry to` and `company name`.

I am getting the output as

```
Send inquiry to:         companyname
                         countryname
```

I want the result as

```
Send Inquiry to:companyname
                countryname
```

Code:

```
 <div class="formmain">

               <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                  <legend class="scheduler-border">INQUIRY DETAILS</legend>

                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <%--<label class="control-label input-label" for="Send Inquiry">Send inquiry to:</label>--%>
                        <%-- <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Send Inquiry">Send inquiry to:</label>--%>
                        <%--<h3>Send inquiry to:</h3>--%>
                       <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Send inquiry to:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-10">
                             <asp:Label ID="lbCompanyname" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                       </div>
                   </div>

                 </div>
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbcountry" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </fieldset>


     </div>
```

I know this is a basic question. I am new to Bootstrap. I tried by putting Padding Property but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem? I'm not seeing it. Maybe someone else will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Send inquiry to:</label>
        <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top">
                <asp:Label ID="lbCompanyname" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbcountry" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's strange. It seemed to work for me. Has it worked for you yet? If not, please send a screenshot of the output you're getting. Thanks!